# Replace dead images with another - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Not sure how possible this is but I would like to have dead images replaced with another such as missing.jpg or something to that effect. Is this possible?

Comment: Look at this question which asks the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `onerror` event to assign the image a new path:

```
function ImgError(source){
    source.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
    source.onerror = "";
    return true;
}

<img src="someimage.png" onerror="ImgError(this);"/>
```

Source: [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images
Good you copied.

Comment: A life with one less mouse click is a life slightly improved :)

Comment: But atleast give some credit.

Comment: Whoops you're totally right, my bad

Comment: @Danpe: Once you share something on SO, it is not longer yours

Comment: @Genesis Internet & Computer Ethics.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) /path/to/logo.gif [NC,L]
```

Although this is not a JQuery answer ... do you specifically require JQuery to resolve this issue ?